# Zef can't install depends

Tags: raku, zef

when I install Cro::HTTP::Client

```
zef install Cro::HTTP::Client
```

It failed with `Could not find Crypt::Random::Extra`, does this relate to cache?

```
===> Searching for: Cro::HTTP::Client
===> Testing: Cro::HTTP:ver<0.8.0>
===> Testing [OK] for Cro::HTTP:ver<0.8.0>
===> Installing: Cro::HTTP:ver<0.8.0>
===> Install [FAIL] for Cro::HTTP:ver<0.8.0>: ===SORRY!===
Could not find Crypt::Random::Extra at line 1 in:
    inst#/Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site
    inst#/Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/vendor
    inst#/Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6
    ap#
    nqp#
    perl5#

===SORRY!===
Could not find Crypt::Random::Extra at line 1 in:
    inst#/Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site
    inst#/Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/vendor
    inst#/Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6
    ap#
    nqp#
    perl5#
```

I wander if it is the cache problem, so I delete the `~/.zef/` and `~/.perl6/resource`, but still failed install the module.

Finally, I reinstall the Rakudo Star, and It works well.

my perl6 version:

```
perl6 -v
This is Rakudo Star version 2019.03.1 built on MoarVM version 2019.03
implementing Perl 6.d.
```

my os version:

```
Mac Mojave 10.14.4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are saying that it was fixed when Rakudo Star was reinstalled, it might have been due to some problem with the previous installation. There does not seem to be any problem at all with the module you mention or its metadata, as is indeed the case since you seem to have installed it correctly. It would have probably been better (as I suggested originally) to uninstall that failing module and install it over again, but if it works for you, it's OK

**Edited to take into account the fact that the problem seemed to be already fixed**

Comment: Thanks you. @jjmerelo.  I encounter this kind of fails 2-3 times. Maybe it's my misoperation. If reproducted in the future, I hope i'm able to trace it.